# Changing the default keyboard shortcuts in iTerm2

Tags: keyboard, iterm

In iTerm2, <kbd>⌘W</kbd> will close the current shell. In Vim, <kbd>Ctrl W</kbd>, by default, sets you up for a window command (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl W</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> moves to the window on the left, etc.)

I am new to using a Mac and haven't got completely used to the Command key, yet. As such, I am *regularly* closing my terminal session accidentally. (Fortunately, I'm running tmux, so my session is preserved, but it's nonetheless getting pretty annoying!)

Is there a way to change keyboard shortcuts in iTerm2? I realise it's probably unlikely and easier to change the Vim keybindings, but I don't want to change what I'm used to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just tested this in Yosemite. If you re-map the keyboard shortcut for "Close" in the System > Keyboard > Shortcuts, then that changes the <kbd>⌘+W</kbd> behavior.

See:
[image]

[image]

Comment: This still works in macOS 12 Monterey!